# 1120: Access of undefined property flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

In my class, I tried using this line:
`trace(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(getQualifiedClassName(TempButton)))`

However, I get this error:
"1120: Access of undefined property flash."

Can someone help me solve this issue? The code is in an AS file under the class  Main that extends as a MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have forgotten to import "getQualifiedClassName" class. This code should work:

```
// remember to import class(es)
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

public class ... {

    // constructor
    public function ... () {
        // you don't have to use that "flash.utils." before you call the function,
        // but you can do that too, if you want
        trace(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(getQualifiedClassName(TempButton)));
    }
}
```